# Clear cairo text in gtk_window

Tags: c, linux, gtk, cairo

I'm have a trouble with a cairo text. 
I write some lines in a gtk_window:

```
cr = gdk_cairo_create(window->window);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 255, 255, 255);
        cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
        cairo_set_font_size(cr, 14.0);

        cairo_move_to(cr, 90.0, 85.0);
        cairo_show_text(cr, "Terror");
        cairo_set_font_size(cr, 12.0);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 30, 254, 145);
        cairo_move_to(cr, 90.0, 105.0);
        cairo_show_text(cr, "Underdogs");
        cairo_move_to(cr, 90.0, 120.0);
        cairo_show_text(cr, "Disziplin");
        cairo_destroy(cr);
```

The problem is that this text should be dynamic, but if I call more than one time the function that writes the text, lines is overlapped.

Is there any method that flushes the previous text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the text with the background color :)

Comment: But this is ugly. I thought in clearing the "surface". Overwrite the text with the background color implies reload my theme every time that i want to write another text.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Cairo FAQ](https://www.cairographics.org/FAQ/#clear_a_surface):

> If you want to clear your surface to a uniform, opaque color then it
> is quite straightforward:
>
> ```c
> /* Set surface to opaque color (r, g, b) */
> cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, r, g, b);
> cairo_paint (cr);
> ```
>
> However, what if you want to clear the surface to something other than
> an opaque color. Simply modifying the above code to use
> `cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 0, 0, 0, 0);` will not work since Cairo
> uses the `OVER` compositing operator by default, and blending something
> entirely transparent OVER something else has no effect at all.
> Instead, you can use the `SOURCE` operator which copies both color and
> alpha values directly from the source to the destination instead of
> blending:
>
> ```c
> /* Set surface to translucent color (r, g, b, a) */
> cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, r, g, b, a);
> cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
> cairo_paint (cr);
> ```
>
> Of course, you won't want to forget to set the default
> `CAIRO_OPERATOR_OVER` again when you're finished. And the most
> convenient habit for doing that is to just use
> `cairo_save`/`cairo_restore` around the whole block:
>
> ```c
> /* Set surface to translucent color (r, g, b, a) without disturbing graphics state. */
> cairo_save (cr);
> cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, r, g, b, a);
> cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
> cairo_paint (cr);
> cairo_restore (cr);
> ```
>
> Finally, to clear a surface to all transparent, one could simply use
> `CAIRO_OPERATOR_CLEAR` instead of `CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE`, in which case
> the call to `cairo_set_source_rgba` would not be needed at all, (the
> `CLEAR` operator always sets the destination to 0 in every channel
> regardless of what the source pattern contains). But the above
> approach with `CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE` is a more general way to clear the
> surface since it allows for "clearing" to a translucent color such as
> 50% red rather than just clearing to entirely transparent.